# Set running timer in TextView from a background Service with Pause and Resume options

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, timertask

I have created a Timer through [Stopwatch class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html#line.76) and implement it successfully in activity.
But i want to continue the timer after closing the application, so i used Service and put the method inside this. Something like below:

MyService.java:

```
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    String workingTime1 = "";

    void startThreadUpdateTimer() {
    final DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("00");
    Timer T = new Timer();
    T.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    workingTime1 = "Your effort is "
                            + format.format(Double.valueOf(stopwatch
                                    .elapsed(TimeUnit.HOURS)))
                            + ":"
                            + format.format(Double.valueOf(stopwatch
                                    .elapsed(TimeUnit.MINUTES)))
                            + ":"
                            + format.format(Double.valueOf(stopwatch
                                    .elapsed(TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                            + " till now for the day";

                    SwipePage.efforttimer.setText(workingTime1);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);

}

void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
    handler.post(runnable);
}
```

*efforttimer* is the TextView in which I want to show my effort time. I think binding service or broadcastreceiver will help here. Implement many ways but not succeed yet.

All helps and suggestions are mostly appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) will be the simplest solution in your case.

In your `MyService` you'll need this code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public static final String ACTION_UPDATE = "MyServiceACTION_UPDATE";
    ...

    private void updateEmitterMethod() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE));
    }
}
```

While in your Activity you'll have:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMyServiceUpdateReciever;
...

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMyServiceUpdateReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                onUpdateMethod();
            }
        };
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMyServiceUpdateReciever, new IntentFilter(MyService.ACTION_UPDATE));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMyServiceUpdateReciever);
}
```

Comment: Then how to run the timer inside the textview..can you help you help me a little bit more OR provide some example....

Comment: You need to call `updateEmitterMethod()` in your Service, when the timer is triggered. In your Activity you need to paste your TextView update logic into `onUpdateMethod()`, that's it.